# Are you still playing a scale if you don't include every note in said scale?

Tags: theory, notation, scales, key

For instance, if you're playing C major, and instead of playing C D E F G A B, you play C D E F G A, or C D E F G, would that still be considered playing in that scale or key? Because I doubt that most music literally just repeats the exact notes found in a certain scale over and over again to create a melody, otherwise most music would sound the same, right? It seems like when someone comments a scale or key that a song is in, the notes usually aren't perfectly arranged in the way that you'd expect that scale to be in. Like, there will be other notes interspersed in that aren't part of that scale, but it is still considered in that scale or key. Also, what if multiple instruments are playing simultaneously? Would you judge the melody's scale by each instrument, i.e. the guitar is in C, the bass is in Gb, etc., or do you judge it by the simultaneous notes just as they appear? Because that seems like it would be incredibly confusing and hard to analyze, and I don't think you'd be able to really judge its scales unless the instruments were playing similar notes or something. I'm sorry if these are stupid questions but I'm having a difficult time understanding scales and keys as a beginner.

Comment: You're still confusing the terms scale and key. A scale must contain every note belonging to it - otherwise it's not that complete scale. Most pieces are in a key - that's signified by the appropriate key signature at the beginning of each line. A piece in a certain key can and will use whichever appropriate notes it needs for that piece. Other, non-diatonic, notes can also be used without 'breaking any rules'. Wasn't this made clear in the last question/answers?

Comment: I thought so but I was still confused. This cleared things up a bit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In spirit, this seems similar to: [Do the notes in a scale have to be played in order?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/78601/do-the-notes-in-a-scale-have-to-be-played-in-order).

> For instance, if you're playing C major, and instead of playing C D E F G A B, you play C D E F G A, or C D E F G, would that still be considered playing in that scale or key?

If the home note was C, it would be considered playing in the **key** of C major. (People don't really talk about 'playing in' a scale, in Western music theory at least).

> Because I doubt that most music literally just repeats the exact notes found in a certain scale over and over again to create a melody, otherwise most music would sound the same, right?

Of course - you're right.

Analogies are never perfect, but let's try one - the [English alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_alphabet).

- If someone asks you to write the English alphabet, you should write ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ. That's the alphabet. You shouldn't write RSVFGOPQWXYZHIJNKLMABCDETU, because that's not the study form of the alphabet.
- If someone tells you to write some words that use the English alphabet, you can write the letters in orders that convey the meaning you want. "CAT", "DOG", "PANGOLIN".
- and if someone tells you to write in English, you will *mostly* be using letters from English, but you might use some letters that are not in the English alphabet: "Send me your résumé". 
  'é' Is not a letter from the English alphabet, but that sentence is still English.

Similarly, in music,

- if someone tells you to "play the C major scale", you should play CDEFGABC.
- if someone tells you to play a sequence of notes or melody using the C major scale, you can use the notes in whatever order you like
- if someone tells you to play in the key of C major, then you will mostly play notes from the C major scale, in whatever order you like, and you might even play some other notes outside C major - as long as your "home note" or *tonic* for the piece is C.

> It seems like when someone comments a scale or key that a song is in, the notes usually aren't perfectly arranged in the way that you'd expect that scale to be in. Like, there will be other notes interspersed in that aren't part of that scale, but it is still considered in that scale or key.

Well, *playing notes outside of the scale* is a different thing to *playing the notes in the scale, but not in order*.

But again, yes, you're right. When we talk about Playing in a *key*, that's a general, overall, description of the piece's tonality, but often notes outside of the scale associated with the key are used. That's the main reason we have [accidentals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accidental_(music)).

> Also, what if multiple instruments are playing simultaneously? Would you judge the melody's scale by each instrument, i.e. the guitar is in C, the bass is in Gb, etc., or do you judge it by the simultaneous notes just as they appear? Because that seems like it would be incredibly confusing and hard to analyse, and I don't think you'd be able to really judge its scales unless the instruments were playing similar notes or something.

From a beginner point of view, you should probably assume that all instruments will be playing in the same key, and mostly playing notes from the scale associated with that key, as in real music that is usually what you will find. If you really find more than one scale in use in a piece, it may be [polytonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytonality) and impossible to describe using one key.

Comment: I was trying to come up with analogies - accents, dialects, etc, so well done! I'd say the *scale* of C major would also contain the C above that last note B. In all scale books, they will start *and* finish on the same letter note. A small thing, but would you agree?

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot. So a key, including the tonic and everything is pretty subjective, huh? From what I've read, it seems like it's just something you know when you hear. Is this accurate?

Comment: @コナーゲティ With simple songs, most people usually agree what key a song is in, but it *can* be subjective - *Sweet home Alabama* is a classic example where people often disagree about what key it's in! Of course with very complex polytonal music, the idea of 'key' becomes less useful.

Comment: Many earlier classical pieces used the key in their titles - Sonata in Eb, Concerto in D minor, Prelude in G, etc.

Comment: So what's the point in identifying the key of a song in the first place?

Comment: @コナーゲティ it depends on the situation - sometimes you don't need to know the key of a piece, sometimes it's helpful to know the key, sometimes you need to know the key *and* some other information, and sometimes there is no identifiable key. It all depends if you're listening, jamming, composing, analysing, playing in an ensemble.... and the characteristics of the music in question. What situation did you have in mind?

Comment: @コナーゲティ - in a jamming or open mic situation, knowing the key is the one basic that one needs. I get people saying things like 'well, it starts on E, then there's B, then it goes to C#m...' Just say it's in E, and the rest, while not exactly mapped out, is easy to navigate - usually!